# Parse title from source code

Tags: php, html, parsing, preg-match, title

i want to parse title from pages code source using title tag, someone made this for me but i dont know whats the problem because its not working, pls if anyone can help i really will appreciate that.
thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
<title></title>
<?php
$url; = '';
preg_match("#<title>(.*)</title>#Ui", file_get_contents($url), $title);
$title = substr($title[1],0,255);
echo "Title $url : ' $title '<br>";
?>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the first semicolon in `$url; = '';`, write it as `$url = '';` and if it doesn't help then we need more info on what you are trying to achieve, where this snippet is used, etc.

Comment: Aydin4ik thanks for your reply, i just want a script to capture some tags like <title>, where i can put link and it capture tags i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gotta fix this line: `$url; = '';` to remove the semicolon after $url. Also, you should echo the result between the `<title>` and `</title>` tags, not after them. And lastly, a better structure for your application will be to execute PHP and then output HTML.

```
<?php
    $url = ''; // <-- insert the URL of choice here, within quotes, starting with http://
    preg_match("#<title>(.*)</title>#Ui", file_get_contents($url), $title);
    $title = substr($title[1],0,255);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
        <title>
           <?php echo $title; ?>
        </title>
    </head>
</html>
```